# PHP/MySQL best practice generation a tracking number

Tags: tracking

I'm working on a call/bug tracking script and whats the best practice when generating unique  tracking ids for each issue.

- is it best to use the index in mysql
- is there another format I could use
- how do i handle the display format, i like to display a 6(345789) digit number.
- if it goes over 6 digit, how do i start over again or how do I handle this?
- or is it best to create a new field and generate the numbers?

suggestions???

thanks

Comment: I would not use a number that you will ever have to start over again with. Seems to just limit yourself for order history and adds unneeded complexity. Instead you could include alphanumeric instead of just numbers, and pick more than 6 digits. something like 12 alphanumeric digits will not run out anytime soon. For instance, UPS uses an 18 digit tracking number. they are alpha numeric although could have a special format. using mixed case can be problematic for user input as people could enter lower case as upper case and whatnot. often times only upper case is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you use all six digit numbers, you must have less than 900,000 records or you will run out of unique values. There is no way around this except to use more digits or change the data type to varchar and allow alphanumeric values. If you don't think you'll ever have 900,000 records, I would use a mysql auto increment column, but set the sequence to start at the first six digit number (100000). You would create your table like this...

```
CREATE TABLE bugs
(
  tracking_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000,
  ...
)
```

So, the first tracking_id generated when you create a record would be 100000, then 100001 and so on. If you insert more than 899,999 records (exceeding 999,999) the number of digits will increase to 7 though.